# Does eclipse compile the java code internally?

Tags: eclipse, javac

I have been using eclipse quite for some time now for writing applications in JAVA. I always keep the "Build Automatically" OFF and manually build the project. I was wondering about two things that are as following.

1. How eclipse shows the compilation errors in the editor when we just save the source file and DO NOT build the project ?
2. Does eclipse invoke ( behind the scene ) a /bin/javac on that java code to do that ?

Please provide inputs on it.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Editor in Eclipse works off of a source model (this is different than entries in the `Problems View`), making it able to verify syntax and do some error checking of its own for references to classes and class members that don't exist. And yes, Eclipse **does** contain its own [Java Compiler](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/) (the Java Language and VM are both well defined specifications, and not tied to any underlying platform or O.S.) and will create the `.class` files for you. If you're not changing things so that Maven or Ant is orchestrating the compile through `javac`, you might as well leave `Automatic Builds` enabled. In that state, Eclipse is either compiling your latest changes or sleeping until more changes are saved to disk.

Comment: From a user's p.o.v. this is essentially true. Internally both invocations, (a) when the editor is computing errors/warnings and (b) when the builder compiles .java to .class files, both are invocations of the same compiler (which ensures, that errors in the editor and in the Problems View talk the same language).

Comment: Thanks Nitin for the nice/precise/comprehensive explanation.